# Python 3.3: can't install packages in a virtualenv

Tags: python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

I'm using python3 in a virutalenv, but no matter which package I try to install with pip, I always get the following error:

```
Fatal Python error: no mem for sys.argv
ValueError: character U+6573552f is not in range [U+0000; U+10ffff]
```

If the package is downloaded, built and installed manually everything works fine.
Any idea?

Comment: Yes it is a Mac OS X.

Comment: There is a known bug in the OS X producing this kind of error, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33459384/unicode-character-not-in-range-when-calling-locale-strxfrm You are probably triggering it somehow.